# Allow accessing to the port :8080 in iptable

Tags: iptables, port

I need to access to my website on port :8080
But for a reason, I can't :

That's what looks like my `iptable -L` https://gist.github.com/28e7a48d91e933c6f377

After searching on serverfault, I've just added :

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

With no effet (even after a iptable restart)

How to allow access of the `port 8080` please (both locally and externally because of the setting i'm going to put for varnish / apache2) ?

EDIT it seems that after a restart of iptable, the rule of allowing the port 8080 has gone:

[after restart](https://gist.github.com/45c9a7c316dc1f494101).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Allowing a specific port in iptables :**

The general form of the rule is :

```
-A INPUT -i <interface> -p <protocol> --dport <port> -j ACCEPT

-I INPUT <rule no.> -i <interface> -p <protocol> --dport <port> -j ACCEPT
```

> Rule no : The index of the chain where you want to add this rule.
>
> Interface : the interface you wont this rule to apply for, don't specify if you want for all, eg eth0, lo. You may want to specify eth0.
>
> Protocol : which protocol you want it for, tcp/udp. TCP in your case
>
> Port : the port no. you want it to apply to. In your case 8080

Make sure it this rule is before an drop all other packets rule.

The reason you statement is not working is probably because you have specified the interface as `lo` instead of `eth0`

**To make the rules permanent :**

If you just add this rule using the command line, the rule will be discarded when you restart, because the iptables will be loaded again from `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. So if you want to make it permanent, you have two choice.

1. Use `iptable-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

   This will save the iptables configuration to the iptables file, from which it will be read when you restart your pc. But in case you have manually edited that file to add comments those will be lost.
2. Manually edit the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file to add this rule to the correct chain. This ensures that comments put in by you are preserved.

***PS : You may need to find the location of your iptables file and the interface name and make changes accordingly.***

Answer (score 1):

you limit your accept rule just to the loopback [by the *-i lo* part]. to allow world-wide access skip that part and run:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

for the best performance your iptables rules should start with:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and only after that other rules should follow.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's working. If i restart iptables, i need to re-enter both of these lines?

Comment: i dont know how does your firewall script looks like. if it's a bash script - put them at the beginning just after cleaning the iptables rules.